# Webcam window lags

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

Whenever I run a `videoCapture()` function on my Lenovo Laptop, the window lags and the frame prints the matrix with 0 values.

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    check, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
```

Comment: It seems that your camera is broken. Can you use it in other app?

Comment: Yep i did use it with the in-built camera application on Windows 10. It's working fine! But not with Opencv